# postgres function for loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, hasura

I have an `orders` table and an `order_products_items` table.
The `order_products_items` has these fields:

- order_id
- product_id
- quantity
- price

I am trying to create a calculated_field: `calculated_total_products_price` in the `orders` table through a `before insert trigger` function that would calculate the total order price by looping through all the `order_products_items` related to the order and multiplying the quantity with the price for every order item.

This is my failed attempt in doing so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_trigger_total_order_price()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare total float := 0.0;
        product record;
  BEGIN
    FOR product IN
      SELECT itm.price, itm.quantity
      FROM order_products_items itm
        INNER JOIN orders ord
        ON itm.order_id  = ord.id
      WHERE ord.id = NEW.id
        LOOP
            total = total + (product.price * product.quantity);
        END LOOP;

      NEW.calculated_total_products_price := total;
      RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $function$
;
```

The trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fn_trigger_total_order_price BEFORE INSERT ON public.orders
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_trigger_total_order_price();
```

Somehow, I do not get any errors, but always get 0 as a result.

Am I missing something? or is there a better/more efficient way of approaching this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why don’t you use SUM() in an aggregate? You almost never need a loop

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop in postgres to achieve this.

A simple [AGGREGATION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-aggregate.html) query would do.

Something like

```
SELECT SUM(quantity * price) 
FROM order_products_items
WHERE order_id = NEW.id
```

You also don't really need to mess with a trigger if you don't want to.

Just make a [view](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/views/) out of the query below and relate it to the `orders` table as something like `order_totals`

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity * price) order_total
FROM order_products_items
GROUP BY order_id
```